# Xml parsing with hive

Tags: hadoop, xml-parsing, hive

I am using hive serDe(https://github.com/dvasilen/Hive-XML-SerDe/wiki/XML-data-sources) for XML parsing and loading it to hive.
Sample XML content:

```
<records>
<record customer_id="0000-JTALA">
<income>200000</income>
<address type="M">
<Flatno>345</FlatNo>
<Street>ABS</street>
<city>QWW</city>
<country>US</country>
<pin>3235</pin>
</address>   
<address type="B">
<Street>ABS</street>
<city>QWW</city>
<country>US</country>
<pin>3235</pin>
</address>    
</record>

<record customer_id="0001-JTALA">
<income>200000</income>
<address type="M">
<Flatno>45</FlatNo>
<Street>fgBS</street>
<city>QWW</city>
<country>US</country>
<pin>3235</pin>
</address>   
<address type="B">
<Street>ABS</street>
<city>QWW</city>
<country>US</country>
<pin>325</pin>
</address>   
<address type="P">
<Street>ABS</street>
<city>QWW</city>
<country>UK</country>
<pin>325</pin>
</address>   
</record>
</records>
```

For every address a row should be created. As per the above sample for first customer 2 records should be created and for second customer 3 records should be created total 5 records, as per my current code only two records are created each for single customer and in address column all the address are concatenated so for the first customer street column has (first address street + second address street).
    Sample query:

```
CREATE external TABLE msg_details(customer_id STRING, income BIGINT, AType String,Flatno String, Street string,city string,country string,pin string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"column.xpath.customer_id"="/record/@customer_id",
"column.xpath.income"="/record/income/text()",
"column.xpath.address_type"="/record/address/@type",
"column.xpath.Flatno"="/record/address/Flatno/text()",
"column.xpath.Street"="/record/address/Street/text()",
"column.xpath.city"="/record/address/city/text()",
"column.xpath.country"="/record/address/country/text()"
"column.xpath.pin"="/record/address/pin/text()"
)
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
location '/user/root/serdeinput'
TBLPROPERTIES (
"xmlinput.start"="<record customer",
"xmlinput.end"="</record>"
);
```

Comment: Could any one help me out !!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write user defined (custom) serdy for XML parsing.
[ or ] 
Write UDF for splitting the Array values containing in the same column values into rows.

The serde which you are using is generic one, which is almost equivalent to the xpath provided by Hive serde, both are having limited features to extract the records only.

I tried 3 other approaches using Lateral view and other ways, but doesn't worked for all the columns in address type.

The only solution for it is to proceed with custom Serde to parse according to your requirements.

```
create external table msg_details3(customer_id string, income bigint, address_type Array<string>,Flatno Array<string>, Street ARRAY<string>,city ARRAY<string>,country ARRAY<string>,pin ARRAY<string>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"column.xpath.customer_id"="/record/@customer_id",
"column.xpath.income"="/record/income/text()",
"column.xpath.address_type"="/record/address/@type",
"column.xpath.Flatno"="/record/address/Flatno/text()",
"column.xpath.Street"="/record/address/Street/text()",
"column.xpath.city"="/record/address/city/text()",
"column.xpath.country"="/record/address/country/text()",
"column.xpath.pin"="/record/address/pin/text()"
)
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat' 
location '/user/cloudera/data'
TBLPROPERTIES (
"xmlinput.start"="<record ",
"xmlinput.end"="</record>"
);
```